# PostgreSQL doesn't generate index-only plan when using NOT-IN but does when using IN with multicolumn covering index

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have two tables: `A(id, x, cid)` and `B(cid)`. I need to fetch some records from A and excluding records with same cid in B.

I have btree index on `A (cid, id)`.

**Query-1 (NOT-IN)**: `select id from a where cid not in (select distinct cid from b);`

**Plan**:

```
Seq Scan on a  (cost=20418.20..340328.83 rows=5128145 width=8) (actual time=367.337..3820.175 rows=169046 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 10087249
   SubPlan 1
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20283.84..20391.33 rows=10749 width=4) (actual time=351.301..357.395 rows=41493 loops=1)
           Group Key: b.cid
           ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17451.87 rows=1132787 width=4) (actual time=0.530..148.063 rows=1132787 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.254 ms
 Execution time: 3827.324 ms
```

It does NOT generate a `index-only-scan` which I think should be reasonable since index `btree on A(cid, id)` is a covering index.

However, if I use IN operator instead, it can generate `index-only-scan`, shown as following:

**Query-2 (IN)**: `select id from a where cid in (select distinct cid from b);`

**Plan**:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=20284.27..420607.83 rows=10256290 width=8) (actual time=290.225..2349.182 rows=10087249 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20283.84..20391.33 rows=10749 width=4) (actual time=290.162..304.054 rows=41493 loops=1)
         Group Key: b.cid
         ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17451.87 rows=1132787 width=4) (actual time=0.042..95.151 rows=1132787 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_a_cid_id on a  (cost=0.43..27.61 rows=961 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.028 rows=243 loops=41493)
         Index Cond: (cid = b.cid)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.197 ms
 Execution time: 2672.898 ms
```

If you may consider because the cardinalities of `A` and `B` are too different, that's true. `A` contains `10256295` rows while `B` contains `41493` distinct `cid`s.

However, if I manually rewrite the `Query-1` to the following `Query-3` with the same logic, but just using `IN`, postgres can still generate a `index-only-scan`, shown as following:

**Query-3 (IN-sub(NOT-IN))**: `select id from a where cid in (select cid from a where cid not in (select distinct cid from b));`

**Plan**:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=325220.51..722952.01 rows=10256290 width=8) (actual time=3741.854..5607.756 rows=169046 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=325220.07..325326.82 rows=10675 width=4) (actual time=3741.133..3763.512 rows=51758 loops=1)
         Group Key: a_1.cid
         ->  Index Only Scan using idx_a_cid on a a_1  (cost=20418.64..312399.71 rows=5128145 width=4) (actual time=377.384..3691.304 rows=169046 loops=1)
               Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 10087249
               Heap Fetches: 0
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20283.84..20391.33 rows=10749 width=4) (actual time=359.015..365.864 rows=41493 loops=1)
                       Group Key: b.cid
                       ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17451.87 rows=1132787 width=4) (actual time=0.455..144.879 rows=1132787 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_a_cid_id on a  (cost=0.43..27.64 rows=961 width=12) (actual time=0.033..0.035 rows=3 loops=51758)
         Index Cond: (cid = a_1.cid)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 2.758 ms
 Execution time: 5617.930 ms
```

So I'm very confused now, whether it's because `NOT-IN` operator itself is too hard/expensive to use `index-only-scan`? Or just because PostgreSQL's Query Optimizer is not smart enough to generate one?

BTW, my experiments are on PostgreSQL-9.6.

Thank you!

**Follow Up** (Mar-28-2019):

Using jjanes's approach, **it works**!

`SET cpu_index_tuple_cost TO 0;`

`SET random_page_cost TO 1;`

**Explain Query-1 again**:

`explain analyze select id from a where cid not in (select distinct cid from b);`

**Plan**:

```
Index Only Scan using idx_a_cid_id on a  (cost=20418.64..188115.26 rows=5128145 width=8) (actual time=308.552..1865.567 rows=169046 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 10087249
   Heap Fetches: 0
   SubPlan 1
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20283.84..20391.33 rows=10749 width=4) (actual time=289.169..297.363 rows=41493 loops=1)
           Group Key: b.cid
           ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17451.87 rows=1132787 width=4) (actual time=0.020..94.442 rows=1132787 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.112 ms
 Execution time: 1871.197 ms
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you tried `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` in comparison?

Comment: +1 for an excellent first question - welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It picks the plan it thinks will be faster.

If you `SET cpu_index_tuple_cost TO 0` and `SET random_page_cost to 1` you will probably find it using the index only scan.

And also find that it is not reliably better, or at least not by much.

Comment: Thank you for the brief and accurate answer! It works!